# TypeError: Cannot convert provided value to EagerTensor. Provided value: 0.0 Requested dtype: int64

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

I am trying to train the transformer model available from the tensorflow official models. I am able to train in cpu without any error but when I try gpu I get the following error:

```
models/official/transformer/v2/transformer.py:143 call  *
    encoder_outputs = self.encode(inputs, attention_bias, training)

models/official/transformer/v2/transformer.py:166 encode
    embedded_inputs = self.embedding_softmax_layer(inputs)

TypeError: Cannot convert provided value to EagerTensor. Provided value: 0.0 Requested dtype: int64
```

I tried tf.cast but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please see [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with another Keras function. One of my parameters was a float by mistake.